# Kohana rewriting urls in .htaccess showing file not found message

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

I'm using Kohana 3.2 framework, I've put the standard .htaccess file in the same folder of the aplication.

my .htaccess file is

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /mysite/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I've tried changing the las line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$0
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* /index.php/$0 [PT]  -  [PT,L]  -  [PT,L,QSA]
```

But it still shows

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php/login was not found on this server.

```
The complete path of the app is /var/www/es/ec/mysite

The complete working URL is http://10.0.0.1/ec/mysite/index.php/login

The complete NOT working URL is http://10.0.0.1/ec/mysite/login
```

Also...

```
Running in Apache 2.2.3 over CentOS 5
```

Any idea???

Answer (score 1):

## I got it!!

Here is how it gets done when the app is inside other folders.

```
The complete path of the app is /var/www/es/ec/mysite

The complete working URL is http://10.0.0.1/ec/mysite/index.php/login

The complete NOT working URL was http://10.0.0.1/ec/mysite/login
```

In /var/www/es/ec/mysite/application/bootstrap.php the Kohana::init stays like this

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/ec/mysite/',
    'index_file'   => FALSE,
    'charset' => 'ISO-8859-1',
));
```

And the .htaccess like this

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* /ec/mysite/index.php/$0
```

## Hope this helps some one else!

## Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try my Kohana .htaccess file

```
# Set environment
SetEnv KOHANA_ENV "development"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I use Kohana 3.2, also.  This rewrite tends to work for most of my projects.

Let me know how it works out!

Comment: Hi Brent Lingle, I try your .htaccess, but it still shows thw "Not Found - The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server." message. For the records I'm using Apache 2.2.3 on a Centos5 server.

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap.php inside Kohana::init set 'index_file' => '',

Comment: Thanks Meliborn, still getting the same message. Also tried with 'index_file' => 'index.php', and with the default param 'index_file' => FALSE. Any idea??

Comment: 'base_url'   => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])